# Ignore NULLs in GROUP BY? Or a better way to combine row that fill gaps in data?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Due to partial duplicates in some of my database, after some `LEFT JOINs` I wind up with several (but not all) rows where I have partial data, along with `NULLs`. For a unique user, one row may have a ZIP code, and another row may have the STATE of that same user.

Let me show you an example:

```
|email            |state |zip   |
|-----------------|------|------|
|unique@email.com |NULL  |40502 |
|unique@email.com |KY    |NULL  |
|other@email.com  |FL    |34744 |
|other@email.com  |FL    |34744 |
|third@email.com  |OH    |NULL  |
```

Rows with full duplicates (such as other@email.com in my example) are easy enough to cleanup with a `GROUP BY` clause, and some people like third@email.com in my example have `NULLs` and that's ok, but for unique@email.com I have the state in one row and zip in another, what is the best way to combine those two into one row?

A desired result would be:

```
|email            |state |zip   |
|-----------------|------|------|
|unique@email.com |KY    |40502 |
|other@email.com  |FL    |34744 |
|third@email.com  |OH    |NULL  |
```

Answer (score 0):

For the data you have provided, you can use aggregation:

```
select email, max(state) as state, max(zip) as zip
from t
group by email;
```

That said, you can probably fix this in the query used to generate the data.  Also, if you want multiple rows for a given `email` in the result set, then you should ask a new question with a clearer example of data.

Comment: Thanks, however if I have two rows with the same email, and different states, then a `MAX()` would just return one of those two states. As you alluded to, if I have distinct data (not NULLs) between those two rows I would want both returned.

Comment: @Polyviny . . . This seems to answer the question that you asked here, which seems to be describing duplicates only based on emails.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.